# How to Globally Access Java Bean Class?

Tags: java

I have one java bean class set values in parsing .My requirement to access this class 
       Globally  but give null pointer exception when use its instance static and assign value in that.Code is as:-

```
private String Responce;
private String Error;
private String Url;
private SIPModle objsip;
private VMModle objvmmodle;
private ArrayList<CustompadModle> objcmodlelist = new ArrayList<CustompadModle>();
private SettingModle objsettingmodle;
private WifiModle objwifimodle;

public String getResponce() {
    return Responce;
}
public void setResponce(String responce) {
    Responce = responce;
}
public String getError() {
    return Error;
}
public void setError(String error) {
    Error = error;
}
public ArrayList<CustompadModle> getObjcmodlelist() {
    return objcmodlelist;
}
public void setObjcmodlelist(CustompadModle objcmodlelist) {
    this.objcmodlelist.add(objcmodlelist);
}
public String getUrl() {
    return Url;
}
public void setUrl(String url) {
    Url = url;
}
public SIPModle getObjsip() {
    return objsip;
}
public void setObjsip(SIPModle objsip) {
    this.objsip = objsip;
}
public VMModle getObjvmmodle() {
    return objvmmodle;
}
public void setObjvmmodle(VMModle objvmmodle) {
    this.objvmmodle = objvmmodle;
}

public SettingModle getObjsettingmodle() {
    return objsettingmodle;
}
public void setObjsettingmodle(SettingModle objsettingmodle) {
    this.objsettingmodle = objsettingmodle;
}
public WifiModle getObjwifimodle() {
    return objwifimodle;
}
public void setObjwifimodle(WifiModle objwifimodle) {
    this.objwifimodle = objwifimodle;
}
```

My requirement is that globle access this bean class globlly.Anyone suggest me

I am getting this object in doinbackground and assign in static object of that class as:
    AsyncTask {

```
    ProgressDialog objprogress = new ProgressDialog(
            UserSettingConfiguration.this);
    ApplicationRequestHandler objhandler = new ApplicationRequestHandler();

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        this.objprogress.setMessage("Please Wait While Loading...");
        this.objprogress.isShowing();
    }

    @Override
    protected ConfigurationSttingModle doInBackground(String... params) {
        objconfigsetting = objhandler.getConfigurationSetting(params[0],
                params[1], params[2], params[3]);
        return objconfigsetting;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ConfigurationSttingModle result) {
        if (this.objprogress.isShowing()) {
            this.objprogress.dismiss();
        }


    }
}
```

And use in a class Advance as;-

```
private static HashMap<String, String> SUMMARIES = new HashMap<String, String>() {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3055562364235868653L;

    {
        String server = UserSettingConfiguration.objconfigsetting.getObjsip().getServer();
        String displayname1 = UserSettingConfiguration.objconfigsetting.getObjsip().getUser();
        String user = UserSettingConfiguration.objconfigsetting.getObjsip().getUser();
        String password= UserSettingConfiguration.objconfigsetting.getObjsip().getPassword();

        put(FIELD_DISPLAY_NAME,displayname1);// "90901");
        put(FIELD_CALLER_ID,displayname1); //"90901");
        put(FIELD_SERVER,server);
        put(FIELD_USERNAME,user);
        put(FIELD_AUTH_ID, "207");
        put(FIELD_PASSWORD,password);
        put(FIELD_PROXY, null);
    }
};
```

Comment: Can you provide the stacktrace, and the snippet of code where this bean is being used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that a singleton pattern will match your requirements.

You must add this code:

```
private static MyJavaBeanClass = null;

public static MyJavaBeanClass getInstance(){
  if(null == instance){
    instance = new MyJavaBeanClass();
  }
  return instance;
}
```

You must change MyJavaBeanClass for the name of your class, and then you can invoke it anywhere like this:

```
MyJavaBeanClass.getInstance().setError("Testing");
```